# Pass data to the layout and partial views on Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-8

I want pass data to a layout, so I add some script to the boot() function in AppServiceProvider.php like that :

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('inc.top', function($view){
        
        $view->with('hosts_summary',Hosts::all());

    });
}
```

I want to do a lot of calculation & comparisions so I like to work by controller so I did that :

```
view()->composer('inc.top', [TopController::class,'show']);
```

but did not work I can't return data, it s obviosly the code is not correct inside of controller.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

According to official doc: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers

Your should code like this

```
view()->composer('inc.top', TopController::class);
```

And your controller have to define compose() method

```
class MyComposer
{
  public function compose(View $view)
  {
    $view->with('count', $this->users->count());
  }
}
```